# Play Multiple ExoPlayer's inside RecyclerView (Inside ViewPager) causes MediaCodec Exception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, exoplayer, android-mediacodec

I am trying to play multiple (10) ExoPlayer's inside RecyclerView inside ViewPager (Running on Samsung Galaxy Note9) and after swiping right and left enough times i got exceptions and the players(that throws the exceptions) stopping play.

You can see a dedicated simple project with that issue here:
https://github.com/matanmarciano/MultiplePlayers.git

My Expected result is
1. Swiping left, right, top and bottom for ever and players keeps play.
2. Single ExoPlayer for each Stream (with videoUrl) for all application life time (I have already implemented it)

The Exceptions is:

```
2019-09-12 17:19:20.780 21989-22074/com.matanmarciano.multipleplayers E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal runtime error.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueInputBuffer(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2635)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.feedInputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:972)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:653)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:575)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:326)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2019-09-12 17:19:20.784 21989-22074/com.matanmarciano.multipleplayers E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Disable failed.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_flush(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.flush(MediaCodec.java:2131)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.flushOrReleaseCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:701)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.flushOrReleaseCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:605)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onDisabled(MediaCodecRenderer.java:581)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onDisabled(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:451)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.disable(BaseRenderer.java:158)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.disableRenderer(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1078)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.resetInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:844)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stopInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:806)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:399)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2019-09-12 17:19:20.839 21989-22074/com.matanmarciano.multipleplayers E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Reset failed.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_stop(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.stop(MediaCodec.java:2084)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.releaseCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:608)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.releaseCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:595)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onReset(MediaCodecRenderer.java:588)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onReset(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:460)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.reset(BaseRenderer.java:164)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.resetInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:853)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stopInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:806)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:399)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2019-09-12 17:19:21.047 21989-22075/com.matanmarciano.multipleplayers E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal runtime error.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2804)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.renderOutputBufferV21(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:999)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:752)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1492)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:652)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:575)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:326)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2019-09-12 17:19:21.048 21989-22075/com.matanmarciano.multipleplayers E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Disable failed.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_flush(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.flush(MediaCodec.java:2131)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.flushOrReleaseCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:701)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.flushOrReleaseCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:605)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onDisabled(MediaCodecRenderer.java:581)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onDisabled(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:451)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.disable(BaseRenderer.java:158)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.disableRenderer(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1078)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.resetInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:844)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stopInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:806)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:399)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2019-09-12 17:19:21.094 21989-22075/com.matanmarciano.multipleplayers E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Reset failed.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_stop(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.stop(MediaCodec.java:2084)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.releaseCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:608)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.releaseCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:595)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onReset(MediaCodecRenderer.java:588)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onReset(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:460)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.reset(BaseRenderer.java:164)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.resetInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:853)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stopInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:806)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:399)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Screenshot:
[image]

**My Estimation:**
Swiping right, left, bottom and up causing renewing the ViewHolder (So playerView renewing also and playerView.setPlayer called, so ExoPlayer surface changed) and ExoPlayer can not overcoming.
If it is sounds true, how can I fix it? There is any way to change this ViewHolder behavior?

Comment: How did u managed to get out of this issue ?